# How to use @ inside href of anchor tag in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my static website which is built in ASP.NET MVC, I'm using social media accounts in a Razor view. I'm getting an error as shown below when using this code:

```html
<li><a class="youtube" href="https://youtube.com/@techiewords" target="_blank">
<i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
```

Screenshot of the error I get:

[image]

How to avoid this error?

Tried to fix this error with an escape sequence by using `@@`.

Comment: `@techiewords` present on your page?

Comment: Did you try @("@techiewords") or @("@")techiewords

Comment: Got the solution and now able to use @ in href. I will try to post my answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply we can use `@Html.Raw("")`

**Working code:**

```html
<li><a class="youtube" href="@Html.Raw("https://youtube.com/@techiewords")" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to avoid this error?

You can initialize an `C#` valiable and then assign the value that is `"@techiewords"` on that variable. Finally call the variable within `{@variable}` this should resolve the error. You can achieve in following way:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    var urlSpecialCharacter = "@techiewords";
}

<li><a class="youtube" href="https://youtube.com/{@urlSpecialCharacter}" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>Test URL</a></li>
```